# Remove mesh editing limit in sculpting

Tags: mesh, interface, edit-mode, sculpting

I'm on Blender 2.9 attempting to sculpt. Earlier in the year in 2.83 I could clearly remember ticking/unticking something to be able to keep endlessly adding/subtracting volume with brushes like Clay Strips by continuously sculpting on a surface. Even if it was facing the camera, I could go in circles and just make a cylinder. Right now the default is to add to some limit, then just keep smoothing it out.

It's not masked, I have dyntopo on etc. I can obliterate the whole mesh by making a massive brush, it's nothing like that. I know it's possible to sculpt functionally endlessly long thin strips by just adding more volume from a small area for example. Right now there's some kind of maximum limit the mesh can be deformed.

*What setting exactly enables limitless volume editing in sculpt mode?*

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the *Accumulate* checkbox in the sculpt tool options of the properties editor.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tool_settings/brush_settings.html#advanced